# Is $B=μ_{0} nI$ for the magnetic field magnitude at the center of the solenoid axis only?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Is $B=μ_{0}nI$ for the magnetic field magnitude at the center of the solenoid axis only, or at any point inside the solenoid as long as it is far enough away from its edges as it is suggested by the figure down below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion that the field is uniform inside the solenoid is based on the assumption that all the field lines are parallel to the axis of the solenoid, both inside and outside, so the integral of $\mathbf B\cdot d\mathbf s$ is zero along both of the vertical sides of the loop.

This is true if, but only if, the solenoid is infinitely long so the field will be uniform only for an infinitely long solenoid. However in practice the field is very close to uniform as long as the solenoid is long compared to its radius.